# Continuous Inverse Fourier Transform

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, fourier

How to find inverse Fourier transform of:

$ X(j\omega) = \frac{cos(3\omega) \cdot cos(\omega)}{\omega^2} $

The answer to this question is:

$ x(t) = \frac{1}{2} y(t + 1) + \frac{1}{2} y(t - 1) $

where

$ y(t) = \frac{6 + t}{2} ; -6 < t < 0 $

$ y(t) = 3 ; t = 0 $

$ y(t) = \frac{6 - t}{2} ; 0 < t < 6 $

How can we solve such inverse transform-based questions?

Comment: Direct utilisation of the Inverse Fourier transform integral for this given Fourier transform is cumbersome without checking an integral table. Instead, try using Fourier properties and Fourier pairs for help. You should know about the $\cos(\omega)/\omega$ and its time-domain pair, and use the advice given by Max below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be homework, so showing effort on your part will be appreciated. For starters, just a hint.

$$X(j\omega) = \frac{\cos(3\omega)}{\omega} \cdot \frac{\cos(\omega)}{\omega}$$
Multiplication in the frequency domain corresponds to convolution in the time domain.